# Regular expression to verify configuration

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to write regular expression in Java to evaluate a configuration defined in my Spring configuration file.

Configuration looks something like

```
myConfig: (abc123, abcd-123*) | (abc123, xyz-124-321) | (abc111, *)
```

where `*` in the above configuration is to say that it can have anything.

I mention one pair of config params inside ( ) and they are separated by `|`. Pipeline (`|`) is used only when there are multiple pairs to be defined: `( ) | ( )`.

It should have at least one pair defined. Something like below

```
myConfig: (abc123, abcd-123*)
```

I tried below code to just verify `(abc123, abcd-123)`. If this works then I can proceed with complex regex to match the first example.

```
String regPattern = "^.([a-zA-Z0-9].,[a-zA-Z0-9].)";
String test = "(123,inteasd)";
System.out.println(test.matches(regPattern));
```

But it is not working as expected. Please let me know how to fix the above one and I am planning to use this pattern matching to each string expression by splitting them using `|` to verify the first example.

I can do this easily by parsing the string and verifying the expected format in java without using regex. But I want to try regular expression to see if this is achievable with java regex.

Comment: A `.` matches only a single character.

Comment: I want only one open bracket ( and hence I tried using .(

Comment: I am totally new to regex and trying to explore it by avoiding to write my own logic to verify this expression

Comment: You should play around first with something like https://regex101.com/ . It doesn't support a Java flavor but e.g. Python regular expressions are very similar.

Comment: Sure. I will try that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work with the [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) documentation. At the very least, you should escape `(` and `)`. In your `"(123,inteasd)"` example you can use

```
"\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+,[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)"
```

Which means `(` followed by 1 or more of any `a-zA-Z0-9`, followed by `,` follwoed by...

Next, `(abc123, abcd-123*)` can similarly be matched by

```
"\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+, [a-zA-Z0-9-]+.\\)"
```

Where the "anything" represented by `*` is matched by `.`. Also, the second entry of the pair now allows hyphens. It's not clear what the exact structure of these groups is (is it `[a-zA-z]-[0-9]` or any combination is possible?) so this is general.

The complex `(abc123, abcd-123*) | (abc123, xyz-124-321) | (abc111, *)` case is tricky, again, because it's not clear what the real restrictions are, but if the second entry of each pair is any combination of `[a-zA-Z0-9-]` followed by anything (`*`), then try

```
"(\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+, [a-zA-Z0-9-]*.\\)(( \\| )|$))+"
```

Which means, breaking it down:

1. A pair: one or more `a-zA-Z0-9` followed by `,` followed by zero or more `a-zA-Z0-9-` followed by anything (`.`). These are surrounded by `(` and `)`.
2. A pair can be followed by either `|` (need to escape `|` because it means logical OR) or the end of the line (`$`).
3. All of the above exists one or more times.

Comment: second entry of the pair is alphanumeric with - and also it can have something like abcd-123* which indicates that it can contain any value starting with abcd-123. If I can come up with a pattern for (abc123, abcd-123*) then I can compile every pair using the same pattern. I will just split the entire line using pipeline and then I will apply the pattern to verify each pair.

Comment: @MLS Isn't that what I showed? `[a-zA-Z0-9-]` is alphanumeric with dash.